# Making my own printf function?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I was wondering how I could do this. I'm mostly puzzled by the N arguments part:

```
printf("Hello, I'm %i years old and my mom is %i .",me.age(),mom.age());
```

I want to make a function that will take a formatted string like this and return a std string.

How is the N arguments part done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`printf` is a variadic function; you can implement your own variadic functions using the facilities provided by `<stdarg.h>`.

In C++, you should avoid variadic functions wherever possible.  They are quite limited in what types they can accept as arguments and they are not type safe.  C++0x adds variadic templates to C++; once support for this feature is widespread, you'll be able to write type safe variadic functions.

In the meantime, it's best to use some other type safe method.  [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/format/index.html), for example, overloads the `%` operator to perform formatting.

Comment: @James McNellis: Why are variadic limited ? I think the only limitation is the stacksize. You can use any type as long as it's interpreted right.

Comment: @Edwin, they are limited in that you cannot pass in a user-defined structure. (E.g. passing an std::string).

Comment: @Edwin:  Among other things, all arguments passed in the variable arguments pack must be POD.

Comment: @Michael:  You can pass a class-type object as long as it is POD.

Comment: @Micheal: ... and you can always pass a pointer to any type or array.

Comment: @James McNellis: @Michael: You both wrong. I knew i have something done with a UDT (a struct with multiple members) and variadic in the past. So I tested it again. No Problem. BTW I didn't use a pointer or reference to the struct.

Comment: @Edwin:  How is what I said wrong?  I clearly said that "you can pass a class-type object as long as it is POD."  The C++ Standard plainly states that for arguments in the variable arguments pack, "if  the  argument  has  a  non-POD  class  type, the behavior is undefined" (C++03 5.2.2/7).  This is exactly what I said above.

Comment: @James McNellis: non POD works equaly well as long as know what you're doing (you need a manual destructor call on it)

Comment: @Edwin:  No, it doesn't.  Read what I just wrote.  _The behavior is undefined._  There is no way to write portable or correct C++ code that passes an object of a non-POD class type as one of the variable arguments to a variadic function.

Comment: @James McNellis: Since you're such an experienced programmer ,i leave in your conviction.